# Can I use a single custom cell for multiple different cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, mvvm, swift3

I have created a single prototype cell which has two labels (mainLabel and subLabel) and an uiimageview. In the uitableview I'd like to have several cells which reuse the prototype and when needed the subLabel is hidden and the uiimageview is changed with different one or with a uiswitch. The two labels have different text for each cell. Do you have any suggestions/hints in order to do it? possibly in a mvvm architecture?

I'll describe what I am doing:

I have a struct (the Model) with two properties: label and sublabel. This is then instantiate by a viewModel which provides text for each cell, done by a method called getModel(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> cellModel { ... }. Finally in UIViewController, in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { ... } I am calling getModel(), using dequeueReusableCell and setting up each cell. 
In getModel() there is a huuuuge switch which I use to know which cell is which

Then in uitableviewcell I have some method that hides sublabel and changes uiimageview.

It kind of works, however I have some issues with while scrolling. For example, sometimes a uiimageview is drawn in another cell, or a subLabel is hidden, even if it is not supposed to. I guess this is due because it is reusing the cell, and I am not resetting it.

Anyway, any suggestions or ideas?

I know this is overkilling...

Answer (score 0):

No need for any pattern. Yes, you can use that single cell design for all cells. Just hide/empty label(s) and image view as you like per cell.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set default value to both the labels and imageview

i.e. (consider a title label, a sub label and a imageview)

```
lblTitle.isHidden = false
      lblSubLabel.isHidden = false
      imgViewIcon.image = nil
```

Then just show labels in specific condition that you want to match and set image in imageview

i.e. (consider your condition to hide sub label)

```
if needToHide == true {
      lblSubLabel.isHidden = true
}
```